# How do I make a subclass of "dict" that returns a fallback value when it can't find a value for a key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class, oop

I want to create `SafeDict`, a subclass of `dict`.

When asked to retrieve a value for a non existing key, `SafeDict` should return a fallback value.
(I know there are other ways to do this, but I'm practicing my OOP skills.)

Right now I have:

```
class SafeDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            super().__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            return "Beetle"

a = {"Ford": "Mustang"}
b = SafeDict({"Ferrari": "Enzo"})

print(a["Ford"])  # This prints "Mustang" (good)
#print(a["Aston"]) # This raises KeyError (good)

print(b["Ferrari"]) # This should print "Enzo", but it prints "None" (bad)
print(b["Aston"])  # This prints "Beetle" (good)
```

Maybe `print(b["Ferrari"])` prints `None` beacuse `super()` runs the `__getitem__` method on the `list` superclass, and that class has no dictionary with `"Ferrari": "Enzo"` in it?

I tried to remove the `super()`, and use `self`, but I ran into recursion problems.

Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to return the super() value:

```
class SafeDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            return "Beetle"
```

When a method has no explicit `return` statement, the function implicitly returns `None`